# Show when $(1+ s t )f(t)\phi(f(t))+3st\Phi(f(t))$ is $>0$ and $<0$

Tags: real-analysis, probability

For $f(t)=\frac{-1}{s\sqrt{t}}<0$.

Is it possible to show that when $(1+ s t )f(t)\phi(f(t))+3st\Phi(f(t))$  is $>0$ and $<0$?

Where $\phi$ and $\Phi$ are the normal pdf and cdf respectively.

Comment: This question feels incomplete. Are there any assumptions on $\phi$ and $\Phi$? In general I do not think there is an answer to this.

Comment: $\phi$ and $\Phi$ are the normal pdf and cdf. Yea i've been thinking long and hard on this. Even being able to show it attains both positive and negative values is useful. I don't need a tight bound

Comment: updated $f(t)$. Numerically, I know it has to take positive and negative values.

Comment: What is the range of $s$ and $t$? Do you mean $f(t) < 0$ for all the values of $s$ and $t$ in that specified range?

Comment: $s$ and $t$ are all $>0$. so that $f(t)<0$.

Comment: Well, why not write down all these hypotheses in the question from the start? Sooo... you are asking for the sign of $$3u(1-\Phi(v))-(1+u)v\phi(v)$$ for $(u,v)$ nonnegative, knowing that $$u=st\quad v=\frac1{s\sqrt{t}}$$ hence $$t=u^2v^2\quad s=\frac1{uv^2}$$ This is also the sign of $$\frac{3u}{1+u}-\frac{v\phi(v)}{1-\Phi(v)}$$ Can you continue?

Comment: Sorry for phrasing the question badly. It's because I was substituting variables from my original equation and trying to make it simpler, as well as being so familiar with the hypotheses that I forgot that it's not obvious at all to someone new to the problem. I apologize.

Comment: Anyway, with regards to the question. Through another approach, I've actually managed to show that it is first positive, and then finally negative, by Intermediate value theorem, it must attain zero. But I am unable to show that it attains zero only once, which is what I'm trying to show now. Using your hint, $2v\phi(v)\leq\frac{v\phi(v)}{1-\Phi(v)}\leq\frac{\phi(1)}{1-\Phi(v)}$, on the right track?

Comment: The original problem is to show that the derivative of $h(t) = \frac{\Phi(\frac{-1}{s\sqrt{t}})}{2(st+1)^{3/2}}$ is first positive, then 0 and then negative. This is how the equation in the question is derived from.  I've managed to prove that the derivative is first positive, then finally negative: $h(t)$ is continuous, $h(0) = 0$, $h(t)\rightarrow0$ as $t$ goes to infinity. Since $h(t)\geq0$, we must have that the derivative is first positive and then finally negative. It's just the uniqueness of the zero now. I am hoping your direction will give some insights.